# Should I ask a question that has an answer in another Q&A site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have just joined with [Sports](https://sports.stackexchange.com/) few days back.
I have a question in my mind and I wanted to post it here, but before posting here I did a google search.

And my question have an answer in another Q&A site(not in an Stack Exchange sites).

But if it is a good question and adds value to our beta community here, can I post the question here?.

Example Questions :

- In which sports do women have better world records than men, [google results](https://www.google.co.in/#q=In+which+sports++women+have+better+world+records)
- 2 wickets off one ball in cricket, [google results](https://www.google.co.in/#q=2+wickets+off+one+ball+in+cricket)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there is no prohibition about asking questions which have been answered elsewhere on the Internet - the aim is for *Stack Exchange* to be the source of truth, not "use Google". However, if it's a very common question, then please try hard to make it a really high quality question so the Stack Exchange Q&A can be significantly better than those elsewhere.

With regards to your specific examples, note that the second [is already answered on Sports SE](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1722/two-dismissals-off-a-single-ball); that question is currently the top result if you search for "[two wickets one ball](https://sports.stackexchange.com/search?q=two+wickets+one+ball)", so please make sure you do thorough searches before doing any of this.